# Atlassian Bamboo and git with Shared Web Hosting, is it possible?

Tags: git, deployment, continuous-integration, web-hosting

**Background:** I recently was hired into an organization where they use a web-development deployment model utilizing Atlassian Bamboo(Continuous Integration) and Bitbucket(git repository).

In my personal web-projects I had always used an ftp client to manually upload changes to a shared web hosting server. I have found that I enjoy the former method, because Bamboo enables  an event trigger that automatically sends along any change sets I push to the remote git repository in bitbucket.(it sends the changes to the production/development server)

Unfortunately I am new to this, and I don't even know if it is possible for me to emulate the setup I have at work, with the shared web hosting service I have been using.(or perhaps one needs to physically own & control a specialized web-server?)

**Question:** Is it possible to configure Bamboo to automatically push repository commits to a server that is part of a shared web hosting plan? If so, what type of steps would I need to take?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and Atlassian has [the documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Triggering+builds). Perhaps for your personal project you could look at open source continuous integration server [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use Bamboo with shared web hosting, unless you are using Atlassian's SaaS offerings. The amount of resources Bamboo would use in a shared environment would get you kicked off the hosting provider.